# Windows XP let you set the space for system restore but I don’t see that in Vista. Where did it go?

Tags: windows-vista

Windows XP let you set the space for system restore but I don’t see that in Vista. It used to be in the system properties so where did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it at the command line now with this command:

vssadmin Resize ShadowStorage /For=C: /On=C: /Maxsize=3GB

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788050(WS.10).aspx

Comment: P.S. Same for Windows 7, btw.

Comment: That's incorrect. In 7, it's use under "System Protection."

Comment: @surfasb Thanks, I did not realize they put it back, so it can be done either way. So technically, my comment is not really incorrect.